# sqrt function in C++

Tags: c++, sqrt

I'm running this code to calculate square root of `x[i][j] - y[j]` but it gives me nonsense!

```
     bool X[I][J]={};   //nodes
     bool Y[J]={};      //medians

    double denominator=0;
    double miu=0;
    outFile<< "denominator= " << denominator << endl;
    for(i=0;i<I;i++)
        for(j=0;j<J;j++)
        {
            denominator+=sqrt(double (X[i][j]-Y[j]));
        }
    outFile<< "denominator= " << denominator << endl;
```

The first `outFile` prints 0 which is the original value but the second one prints `-1.#IND`.

Comment: `X[I][J]` & `Y[J]` already contain the nonsense, if they are local variables & are not initialized. So *You would reap what you sow* and thats *nonesense* values.

Comment: do u have any spl reson to find the sqrt of 2 bool values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably means that at some point `X[i][j] - Y[j]` was negative, and you're getting a NaN (not a number) back from `sqrt`.

See [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) for an explanation of NaNs.

Also, `X` and `Y` are arrays of booleans, so `X[i][j] - Y[j]` will always be 1, 0, or -1, and you really don't need the `sqrt`. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't take the square root of a negative number - you get an imaginary number. Just use `abs` to retrieve the absolute value of the difference first:

```
bool X[I][J] = {};   // nodes
bool Y[J] = {};      // medians

double denominator = 0;
double miu = 0;
outFile << "denominator= " << denominator << endl;
for(i = 0; i < I; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < J; j++)
    {
        denominator += sqrt(double (abs(X[i][j]-Y[j])));
    }
outFile << "denominator= " << denominator << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be taking the square root of a negative number - leads to the value you see which essentially means "not a number"

Answer (score 0):

Since both X and Y are bool, there are chances for the argument that is passed to sqrt() to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the same results you do, I get zero for both.

http://ideone.com/25ZPf

The initializers for both arrays should set all values to zero, so the square root of the subtraction should be zero as well. The fact that they're boolean arrays shouldn't matter since the values will be upcasted to 0.0.

Something tells me the code you posted isn't the actual code that's causing the error.